# Ajax URL call not working in MVC 4 using javascript

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to MVC 4 using razor application.

I have a file upload control and submit button which to upload file and submit file to the  particular directory (specified in below code) in local computer.

**My Requirement:**

If file is already exists in that specified directory of file path, i have to ask confirmation whether to over write or create back up of a file .

i am displaying confirmation message as "File already existed, Do you want to overwrite?"

If user clicked

**OK/YES**  ----   I have to create overwrite of a file

**CANCEL/NO** ----   I have to create backup of a file

I am able to display confirmation message correctly and able to select either OK/YES or

CANCEL/NO .

**Note:**  1)  I should not use model in my application

2) I am using action methods in same controller.

3) I have created "UploadeFiles" folder in my E:\ drive

**Problem:**

After clicking OK/YES or CANCEL/NO , neither of ajax url's  reaching to controller method nor nothing working. I am stuck to here.

Note: But the alert messages corresponding to Overwrite or Backup are working if i click OK/YES or CANCEL/NO

**My VIEW:**

```
@if (TempData["FileExists"] != null)

    {

    <script type="text/javascript">
           if (confirm("File Already Existed, Do you want to over write?"))
            {
                alert("Proceed for over writing file");
                var Url = "@Url.Content("~/Documents/OverWrite")";
                $.ajax({
                    url: Url,
                     type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: { docfileName: "FileData" },
                    success: function (data)
                    {
                        alert("overwrite success")
                    }
                });
             }                  
             else 
             {
                alert("Create Backup");
                var Url = "@Url.Content("~/Documents/CreateBackup")";
                  $.ajax({
                   type: 'POST',
                   url: Url,
                   dataType: 'json',
                   data: { docfileName: "FileData"},
                   success: function (data) { alert("Backup success") }
                });
            }
        }
</script>
    }


@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))

{

@Html.ValidationSummary(true)


    <label style="width: 300%;"for="fileToUpload">Upload File</label>
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Create" id="btnCreate"/>


}
```

**My CONTROLLER**

MVC Controller Name:  **DocumentsController**

```
public ActionResult CreateDocuments(HttpPostedBaseFile fileToUpload)

{

    string fileName = Path.GetFileName(fileToUpload.FileName);

    string fileToUploadPath= @"E:\UploadFiles\";

    string fileTotalPath = Path.Combine(fileToUploadPath, fileName);

   if (System.IO.File.Exists(fileToUploadPath)

     {

     TempData["FileExists"] = "Yes";

      return PartialView("CreateDocument");

     }

}


[HttpPost]


public ActionResult OverWrite(string docfileName)

        {

             JsonResult resultOverWrite= new JsonResult();

            string ajaxdata=docfileName;

            // Here i am writing code for Overwriting a document file

            return resultOverWrite;
        }




public ActionResult CreateBackup(string docfileName)

        {

            JsonResult resultbackup= new JsonResult();

            string ajaxdata=docfileName;

           // I am writing here for back up coding


            return resultbackup;
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

you are using wrong helper method:

change:

```
@Url.Content("~/Documents/OverWrite")
```

to:

```
@Url.Action("OverWrite","Documents") 
// first parmeter action name, second parameter controller name
```